# Using WHERE clause in mySQL and searching for a a string in two columns

Tags: mysql, search

I have a query that searches a 'string' in two fields, FIELD_IMPORTANT and FIELD_2.

I want to have the result;

IF the 'string' is found in FIELD_IMPORTANT THEN order the results with the records having the 'string' in FIELD_IMPORTANT at the TOP,
and then the others...

Is it possible ?

Up to now I have the following:

```
SELECT
expert.expert_name, naf_add.FIELD_IMPORTANT, naf_level_5.FIELD_2,
ROUND(AVG(expert_rating.rating_global)) AS avg_rating_global

FROM naf_nomenclature

LEFT JOIN naf_add ON naf_add.naf_add_naf_level_5_code = naf_nomenclature.level_5_code
INNER JOIN naf_level_5 ON naf_level_5.level_5_code = naf_nomenclature.level_5_code
INNER JOIN expert ON expert.expert_level_5_code = naf_nomenclature.level_5_code
LEFT JOIN expert_rating ON expert_rating.rating_expert_id = expert.expert_id


WHERE 
naf_add.FIELD_IMPORTANT  LIKE '%elec%' OR
naf_level_5.FIELD_2 LIKE '%elec%'

GROUP BY expert.expert_name

ORDER BY fword DESC, avg_rating_global DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by (naf_add.FIELD_IMPORTANT LIKE '%elec%') desc,
         fword, avg_rating_global
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with "0" for false and "1" for true.  So, when the expression is true, then the value of the first key is "1".  The `desc` puts these first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's amazingly intuitive !